# C# MVC4 noob - define interface with DbContext Entry method included

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, interface, dbcontext

I am trying to learn C# coming from a classic ASP/VBScript background.

Up front (just in case someone can answer without all the following background info and code) - My DbContext interface doesn't allow me to do this:

```
_dbcontext.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

It balks at me trying to use the Entry method with the following error:

'MyNamespace.Models.IMyDataContext' does not contain a definition for 'Entry' and no extension method 'Entry' accepting a first argument of type 'MyNamespace.Models.IMyDataContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How can I properly define my interface so that it will include the Entry method from the DbContext class?

BACKGROUND

I had someone who (supposedly) knows their stuff help me get the following code setup for connecting to MSSQL or MySQL based on data we retrieve from a common connection info table. The schema in MSSQL and MySQL is identical for the data model.

```
public interface IMyDataContext
{
     DbSet<MyModel> ModelData { get; set; }
}

public class dbMySQL : DbContext, IMyDataContext
{
     protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
     {
          var table = modelBuilder.Entity<MyModel>().ToTable("tablename");
          table.HasKey(t => t.Id);
          table.Property(t => t.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
          table.Property(t => t.Key);
          table.Property(t => t.Value);
          base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
     }
     public dbMySQL(DbConnection existingConnection, boolcontextOwnsConnection) : base(existingConnection, contextOwnsConnection) { }

     public DbSet<MyModel> ModelData { get; set; }
}

public class dbMSSQL : DbContext, IMyDataContext
{
     protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
     {
          var table = modelBuilder.Entity<MyModel>().ToTable("tablename");
          table.HasKey(t => t.Id);
          table.Property(t => t.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
          table.Property(t => t.Key);
          table.Property(t => t.Value);
          base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
     }
     public dbMSSQL(string connectionString) : base(connectionString) { }

     public DbSet<MyModel> ModelData { get; set; }
}
```

Using the above code, I have been able to successfully grab connection info from a table and return a DbContext as follows:

```
    private IMyDataContext selectDbProvider(int Id)
    {
        // Get database connection info
        var connInfo = _db.ConnModel.Find(Id);
        string dbProvider = connInfo.dbType.ToString();

        IMyDataContext _dbd;
        if (dbProvider == "MySql.Data.MySqlClient")
        {
            var connectionStringBuilder = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
            connectionStringBuilder.Server = connInfo.dbServer;
            connectionStringBuilder.UserID = connInfo.dbUser;
            connectionStringBuilder.Password = connInfo.dbPassword;
            connectionStringBuilder.Database = connInfo.dbName;
            connectionStringBuilder.Port = 3306;
            _mysqlconn = new MySqlConnection(connectionStringBuilder.ConnectionString);
            _dbd = new dbMySQL(_mysqlconn, false);
        }
        else
        {
            var connectionStringBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
            connectionStringBuilder.DataSource = connInfo.dbServer;
            connectionStringBuilder.UserID = connInfo.dbUser;
            connectionStringBuilder.Password = connInfo.dbPassword;
            connectionStringBuilder.InitialCatalog = connInfo.dbName;
            _dbd = new dbMSSQL(connectionStringBuilder.ConnectionString);
        }

        return _dbd;
    }
```

Using all of the above, I can successfully access data in either MySQL or MSSQL:

```
    _dbd = selectDbProvider(Id);
    model = _dbd.ModelData.ToList();
```

However, when I try to do an update operation, I get the error message I mentioned at the top. How can I properly define my interface so that it will include the Entry method from the DbContext class?

Comment: I think it would make more sense for this purpose to use a factory instead of trying to implement it as interface. In other words, you would just have a class that with a method like `GetContextFor(Id)`, that would simply return  an instantiated version of your application's context with the appropriate provider set.

Comment: Chris, I removed IMyDataContext so that the MySQL and MSSQL DbSet builders now only derive from DbContext. Then using my existing selectDbProvider function, I changed it to return a DbContext instead of IMyDataContext. However now when I try _dbd.ModelData it does not recognize it - System.Data.Entity.DbContext does not contain a definition for ModelData.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a method to your interface for it.

```
DbEntityEntry Entry(Object entity)
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696238(v=vs.113).aspx

EDIT:

```
public class dbMyContext : DbContext
{
    //snip

    public dbMyContext(DbConnection existingConnection, boolcontextOwnsConnection) : base(existingConnection, contextOwnsConnection) { }

    public dbMyContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString) { }

    //snip

}
```

Adjust your `selectDbProvider` class to use dbMyContext instead of dbMySQL and dbMSSQL.

Now you're using an O/RM properly. :)

Comment: Hmm, I added exactly what was shown on that page and it says "The modifier 'public' is no valid for this item" with the blue line under the method name Entry.

Comment: Yes, you can't have modifiers in interfaces. Take out the public and it should be happy.

Comment: That worked! Apparently my reputation isn't enough to successfully vote up your answer. Thanks!

Comment: You should still be able to select it as the answer. I'm glad I could help!

Comment: I did, it just doesn't contribute to the score I guess. Thanks again.

Comment: Following up (and this was my fear) - since none of the DbContext methods/properties appear to be inherited in the interface, it seems I'm going to have to add them in manually as needed, which is a pain. For example, now I am trying to do _dbd.SaveChanges() but "IMyDataContext does not contain a definition for SaveChanges."  It seems like there should be an easier way to do this and my rookie-ness is preventing me from knowing what to do.

Comment: To be honest, the person who gave you the code is making it unnecessarily complex. The whole point of the DbContext is to hide database operations, so making a different one per database type doesn't make sense to me. Go down to one DbContext class (and name it something that makes sense to your application, not what database it connects to) and put both constructors in there. If that doesn't make sense, let me know.

Comment: I had a gut feeling that was the case, but without the adequate experience to know better I wasn't sure. I've tried some yesterday and this morning to do what you suggested and I must not be doing it right. I truly appreciate your willingness to help. I'm not sure if this is the best place to try and maintain this discussion, but I can't seem to find a way to private message you.

Comment: I just got it! Took me about a half dozen or more iterations to finally figure it out, but I got it. Still not sure if it is the most elegant solution, but it works and it takes out that interface and reduced the amount of code significantly. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction Spivonious!

Comment: I'm glad I could help!